# How many prime ideals does $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^m -1)$ have? (multiple choice)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer, and $a_m$ denote number of distinct prime ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^m -1)$. Then which of the following are true?

1. $a_4=2$
2. $a_4=3$
3. $a_5=2$
4. $a_5=3$

Comment: I mean, more often than not (but not always!!) these type of problems become progressively more laborious as the parameter grows. So if you can't do $m=4$ right away, work out a smaller case first. Are you familiar with a suitable result that relates the ideals of a quotient ring $R/I$ to a subset of ideals of $R$? What does such a result say about prime ideals? What do you know about prime ideals of a ring of polynomials with coefficients in a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks  @Andreas Caranti.

I thought that it will be good to write the answer.

The point which I got from here is $\mathbb Q[x]/\left<x-1\right>$, $\mathbb Q[x]/\left<x+1\right>$, $\mathbb Q[x]/\left<x^2+1\right>$ are fields as $x-1, x+1, x^2 +1$ are irreducible polynomials so those ideals are maximal. Hence all these are integral domains and so $\left<x-1\right>,\left<x+1\right>,\left<x^2+1\right>$ are prime ideals.

I found that each of these are subfields of $\mathbb Q[x]/\left<x^4-1\right>$. So using Andreas Caranti's comment we can conclude that **$\mathbb Q[x]/\left<x^4-1\right>$ has $3$ prime ideals.**

Same type of argument is valid for $\mathbb Q[x]/\left<x^5-1\right>$.

Comment: These are **not** subfields of $\Bbb Q[X]/\langle x^4-1\rangle$ but quotient fields. Also this shows that there are _at least_ $3$ prime ideals; to show there are exactly $3$, a bit more reasoning is required.

Answer (score 3):

$$
x^4 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)
$$
and
$$
x^5 - 1 = (x-1) (x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)
$$
are the decomposition of the two polynomials as products of irreducibles in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. So it seems to me that  (2) and (3) both hold.

Comment: Thanks.The point which I got from here is $\mathbb Q[x]/<x-1>$,$\mathbb Q[x]/<x+1>$,$\mathbb Q[x]/<x^2+1>$ are fields as those polynomials are irreducible so those ideals are maximal.Hence all these are integral domain and so those ideals are prime ideals. But now I got a question that what is the relation between $\mathbb Q[x]/<x-1>$ and  $\mathbb Q[x]/<x^4-1>$?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^4-1 \rangle \cong  \Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x-1 \rangle \oplus \Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x+1 \rangle \oplus\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, by the Chinese remainder theorem for polynomials.

Comment: Thanks I just now write the full solution using your hints  more clearly.